# ORACLE DISTINCT inside a function

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, ora-hash

I am trying to use the following on oracle 11g:

```
select sum(ora_hash(distinct attribute) from table;
```

This gives me the error:ORA-00936: "missing expression"

I was expecting this to work, as for example
    sum(distinct attribute) from table;
works fine.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a curious construct.  I would recommend either:

```
 select sum(distinct ora_hash(attribute) from table;
```

(although `sum(distinct)` is almost never the right construct.)

Or:

```
select sum(ora_hash(attribute))
from (select distinct attribute from table) t;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, this worked fine for me. For my context of comparing data content from one datamart to another, sum(distinct) may look weird, but does its job.